# Question about finding an orthogonal matrix of an orthogonal matrix which can be written as $C^{tr}MC$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices, unitary-matrices

Sorry guys, I have a problem about finding an orthogonal matrix $C \in Mat_{nxn}(\mathbf R)$ such that
$$
C^{tr}MC=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda &0&0\\
0 &cos(\alpha)&sin(\alpha)\\
0 &-sin(\alpha)&cos(\alpha)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix $M \in Mat_{nxn}(\mathbf R)$, and
$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I tried firstly by looking for a matrix which is formed by normalized eigenvector of $M$, but I only found one eigenvector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then I have no idea what should I continue.

Thanks in advance, for your attention and your help.

Comment: Is $C$ meant to be a real matrix? Typically, "unitary" matrices are allowed to have complex entries; did you mean to say that $C$ is "orthogonal"?

Comment: @BenGrossmann sorry i'll rewrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there are many ways to go about this question. Here is a quick (but unconventional way) to get an answer.

In fact, it suffices to get **any** orthogonal matrix $C$ whose first column is the normalized eigenvector $\frac 1{\sqrt 3}(1,1,1)$. One convenient such matrix is the [Householder matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) that reflects across the plane perpendicular to $v = \frac 1{\sqrt 3}(1,1,1) - (1,0,0) = \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}(1-\sqrt{3},1,1)$.  That is, it suffices to take
$$
C = I - 2 \frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}, \quad v = \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}(1-\sqrt{3},1,1).
$$
With computation, that comes out to
$$
C = \pmatrix{1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{3}\\
1/\sqrt{3} & 1/2 - \sqrt{3}/6 & 1/(\sqrt{3} - 3)\\
1/\sqrt{3} & 1/(\sqrt{3} - 3) & 1/2 - \sqrt{3}/6}.
$$